# nmap scan with netbios/bonjour name

Tags: nmap

Is there any fancy way in Nmap to scan hosts plus getting the netbios/bonjour name as Fing app does?

I've been looking at the -A argument, it's fine but it does a lot of another scripting stuff and takes more time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

nmap -sU -p 137,5353 --script [nbstat](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/nbstat.html),[dns-service-discovery](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/dns-service-discovery.html) $targets